# What does the percentage mean when enemies are destroyed?

Tags: gundam-evolution

Whenever an enemy player is destroyed there's a percentage next to the kill message. What does the percentage mean?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The percentage indicates how much damage you contributed to the kill as compared to other players. Each player that damaged an enemy before it was defeated will see a different percentage.